# How to insert Hotjar code to nuxt project

Tags: nuxt.js, hotjar

I want to add hotjar to my nuxt project. I know that for adding google analytics I need to add it as a plugin according to the documentation of nuxt: https://nuxtjs.org/faq/google-analytics. But I don't know what is the best way to add htjar to the project.

Answer (score 3):

I did it the same way as the google-analytics documentation.

1. Add hotjar to plugins in your nuxt.config:

   plugins: [
     {src: '~/plugins/hotjar.js', mode: 'client'}
   ]
2. Add a hotjar.js file to your plugins directory with your tracking code inside.

I'm also curious if there is a better way

Comment: Try this:

// nuxt.config.js
{
  // ...
  plugins: ['~/plugins/hotjar']
}
Then add implementation code (without the script tags) to plugins/hotjar.js

// plugins/hotjar.js
(function (h, o, t, j, a, r) {
your code...
}

Comment: An other option is to implement hotjar via a tag in Google Tag Manager. @ShadiFarzankia

Comment: It doesn't work for me and the Hotjar error is : `Please check you’ve correctly pasted the Hotjar tracking code into your site’s header`.
It can not find the code

Answer (score 1):

For Nuxt3 you can use [vue-hotjar-next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-hotjar-next), for Nuxt2 you can use [vue-hotjar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-hotjar).

Install the package:

`npm install vue-hotjar-next`

Create a new plugin in your plugins directory (plugins/vue-hotjar-next.client.js, note the .client part):

```
import VueHotjar from "vue-hotjar-next";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VueHotjar, {
        id: <YOUR_SITE_ID_AS_A_NUMBER>,
        isProduction: process.env.IS_PRODUCTION, // <-- or simply true/false
    });
});
```

Use it in your nuxt.config.ts:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    plugins: [
        "~/plugins/vue-hotjar-next.client.js",
    ]
}
```

Wait around 15-60 minutes for the data to show up in the Hotjar dashboard. You can verify it's working by checking the network tab in your dev tools and looking for a successful GET call `hotjar-<site_id>`.

Answer (score 0):

I wondered if we could put the script into the `head` property of the  `nuxt.config.js` according to **manual setting** of Hotjar that said it should be on the .

I think we could use [this](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/api/#script) for doing so, but I am not sure. I will look forward to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here after continually getting the error:

```
hotjar Tracking code not found 
Please check you’ve correctly pasted the Hotjar tracking code into your site’s header.
```

But I was sure I had done everything correctly.

I had uBlock Origin (an adblocker) in my browser, so the hotjar script wasn't being run. Hotjar don't tell you this in their instructions but the site must be accessed by at least one browser with **adblockers turned off**.

Once I visited the site with a broswer without adblockers, hotjar verification worked immediately. Hope this saves someone else some time.